# How to insert data in MS Access database having field with data type memo using java

Tags: java

Hi friends I am developing an insurance domain application. My back end is MS Access 2010. I have two columns in table permanent address and communication address, both have data type memo. Now the problem is when I try to insert the data from front end application it gives an error "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: data exception: invalid character value for cast". I am unable to solve the problem. Can anyone help me with suggestion. I codes are below

```
JButton btnAdd = new JButton("ADD");
        sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, btnAdd, -35, SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
            {
                java.sql.Statement stmt=null;
                ResultSet rset=null;

                Calendar currcal=Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat df;
                df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                Date getcurrdate=currcal.getTime();
                String currdate=df.format(getcurrdate);

                try
                {
                    stmt=dbcon.DB_Connection("//F://eclipse_Luna_64_Development_Workspace//Project JAVA//LIC_AGENCY_TRACKER//DATABASE//LIC_DATA_TRACKER.accdb").createStatement();
                    rset=stmt.executeQuery("select count(Inquiry_Master_ID) as total from Inquiry_Master_Data");
                    String getmaxusrid=null;
                    while(rset.next())
                    {
                        int id;
                        id=rset.getInt("total");
                        id++;
                        getmaxusrid="INQ_"+id;
                    }
                    if(getName.length()!=0 && getMobileNo.length()!=0 && getLandLineNo.length()!=0 && getDateOfBirth.length()!=0 && getPlaceOfBirth.length()!=0 
                            && getWorkPlace.length()!=0 && getDateOfEnquiry.length()!=0 && getReference.length()!=0 && getPermenantAddr.length()!=0 
                            && getCorrespondentAddr.length()!=0 && getEmail.length()!=0 && getProfession.length()!=0 && getEducation.length()!=0 && getSex.length()!=0
                            && getHaveInsurance.length()!=0 && getNextFollowupDate.length()!=0)
                    {
                        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into Inquiry_Master_Data(Inquiry_Master_ID,Inquiry_Master_Name,Inquiry_Master_Mobile_Number,Inquiry_Master_Landline_Number,"
                            + "Inquiry_Master_Date_Of_Birth,Inquiry_Master_Place_Of_Birth,Inquiry_Master_Place_Of_Work,Inquiry_Master_Date_Of_Inquiry,Inquiry_Master_Reference,"
                            + "Inquiry_Master_Permanent_Address,Inquiry_Master_Communication_Address,Inquiry_Master_Email,Inquiry_Master_Profission,Inquiry_Master_Education,"
                            + "Inquiry_Master_Sex,Inquiry_Master_Insurance_YN,Inquiry_Master_Insurance_Company,Inquiry_Master_Product,Inquiry_Master_Next_Followup_Date,"
                            + "Inquiry_Master_Creation_Date)values('"+getmaxusrid+"','"+getName+"','"+getMobileNo+"',"
                            + "'"+getLandLineNo+"','"+getDateOfBirth+"','"+getPlaceOfBirth+"','"+getWorkPlace+"','"+getDateOfEnquiry+"','"+getReference+"','"+getPermenantAddr+"','"+getCorrespondentAddr+"',"
                            +"'"+getEmail+"','"+getProfession+"','"+getEducation+"','"+getSex+"','"+getHaveInsurance+"','"+getInsuranceCompany+"','"+getProductType+"','"+getNextFollowupDate+"','"+currdate+"')");
                    }
                    else if(getName==null && getMobileNo==null && getLandLineNo==null && getDateOfBirth==null && getPlaceOfBirth==null 
                            && getWorkPlace==null && getDateOfEnquiry==null && getReference==null && getPermenantAddr==null 
                            && getCorrespondentAddr==null && getEmail==null && getProfession==null && getEducation==null && getSex==null && getHaveInsurance==null && getNextFollowupDate==null )
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter the details properly. No field can be left blank","Error Message",JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
                        txtName.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        });
        btnAdd.setMnemonic('A');
        btnAdd.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 11));
        contentPane.add(btnAdd);
```

Comment: Start by using `PreapredStatement`, see [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).  What JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: Hi I am using ucanaccess-2.0.9.3 for my db connection. I tried with Prepared Statement but it is giving me the same issue. The error is "invalid character value for cast".

Comment: From what I've read, memo is just a String type. Which column is the memo column?

Comment: Inquiry_Master_Permanent_Address, Inquiry_Master_Communication_Address and Inquiry_Master_Product are of Memo data type columns.

Comment: Hi I have rectified the issue as the problem was with the boolean field column. I have changed the field data type. Now the code is working fine.